# gcc does not compile code that compiles in 'as'

Tags: assembly, assembler

I'm trying to learn assembly using the raspberry pi. I have code that compiles using `as` but will not compile with `gcc`. I thought that `as` was the backend for `gcc` assembly so I'm confused why it is not working. It says that `udiv` is undefined.

**test.s**

```
            .global _start
_start:     
            MOV     R4, #3
            MOV     R1, #999

            UDIV    R2, R1, R4

            MOV     R7, #1
            SVC     0
```

Compiling with `as -o test.o test.s; ld -o test test.o` works ok,
Compiling with `gcc test.s -o test` fails.

Comment: Gcc may pass options to as which enable/disable specific features, e.g. FPU opcodes. Check -mfloat-abi http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Comment: A Raspbery Pi is the right platform for learning :-) But your question does not belong essential to Raspberry Pi. It is a general programming question and I believe you will get better and quicker answers at https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Ingo, I guess so, but I felt that assembly related stuff is very system specific, so I might get best results from this board.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell gcc the architecture when just assembling like this. So `gcc -march=native -o test test.s` tells it to assemble for your native architecture (arm on a RPi).

This will yield link errors about multiple definitions of _start and crt1.o. Gcc expects to link in the C runtime which actually provides _start normally and that then calls main. You can prevent this by passing `-nostdlib` to the link stage so finally you should be ok using:

```
gcc -march=native -nostdlib -o test test.s
```

To see what gcc actually does with this, add `-v` and it will show the full as command with all necessary options (`-march=armv7ve -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -meabi=5` on my Pi 2)

Comment: When I used `-march=native` it didn't work, but when I used `-march=armv8-a` it did.